# Is there way to extern typedef variable

Tags: c, structure, typedef, extern

I've file `f1.h` contains huge number lines of declarations etc.
say I've variable `typedef struct abc_t ABC;`

I wanted to get size of the `ABC` in `f2.c` without including `f1.h` & utility function, since I don't want other declaration of `f1.h` needed in `f2.c` that unnecessarily increases binary size.

I just need only `sizeof ABC`.

- Its `typedef` variable, how should we get its size in `f2.c`?
- Is there any method to achieve this?

Comment: Under what circumstances would you need to know the size of a variable in a translation unit that has no access to it or its type? Sounds like the kind of thing you'd want to avoid f2.c having to know.

Comment: The line `typedef struct abc_t ABC;` defines an alias `ABC` for a type `struct abc_t`.  It does not define a variable of that type.  Why does `f1.h` contain such a massive number of declarations that you're reluctant to include it?  Split it up into smaller pieces, maybe leaving behind an omnibus `f1.h` that more only does `#include "f1a.h"`, `#include "f1b.h"`.  The division should be logical, of course, and most client source files should include a few of the specific headers rather than the omnibus header.  It sounds like a self-inflicted wound, probably caused by gradual feature creep.

Comment: this scenario i was practiced in case of f1.h not owned by, it has previously huge number line of declarations. I agree we shouldn't have such its bad practice, if so i should store size in extern to reflect in another .c file. Completely agree i should reorganize the code, before do any addition. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply declare another variable to store the size. So in some header - not f1.h - you would have

```
extern unsigned size;
```

while in f1.c you need to define it

```
unsigned size = sizeof(<whatever type you want>)
```

Comment: Wojtek, how does your suggestion helps, say f1.h contains extern unsigned sizel; typedef struct abc_t ABC;  In f1.c #include "f1.h" unsigned size = sizeof (ABC);  I wanted to get sizeof (ABC) in f2.c without including f1.h file. helps in getting size of struct abc_t

Comment: It helps if you put size not in f1.h, but in another header, say f1size.h. Then this header should be included by both f1.c and f2.c.

Comment: your right i got you.Surprised how does above comment added since i've withdrawn it. Thanks Wojtek.